# Rewriting /user to profile.php?u=user with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, rewriting

I have a site with a dynamic url as (www.abc.com/profile.php?u=me), where the GET variable "u" points to the current viewed user (i.e. me). I want the rewrited URL to look something like this www.abc.com/me.
When I use a URL generator, here is what I mostly get:

```
RewriteRule profile/u/(.*)/ profile.php?u=$1
RewriteRule profile/u/(.*) profile.php?u=$1
```

which points to www.abc.com/profile/u/me and this page doesn't also include css files.
I need something like www.abc.com/me which also includes the page's css files.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: I have a site with dynamic urls like www.abc.com/profile.php?u=user1 but I want to use url-rewriting to convert them to www.abc.com/user1. This is what I did --  RewriteRule profile/u/(.*) profile.php?u=$1 -- , but got this www.abc.com/profile/u/user1 instead of www.abc.com/user1

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?u=$1 [NC,L]
```

This will rewrite  `example.com/user` to `example.com/profile.php?u=user` .

**Why are css files not loading?**

This is because your relative URIs have their base changed. Originally, the base is `/` when the page is `/profile.php?u=user`, and the browser properly fills in relative links with the `/` base. But when the browser goes to a page like `/user` the base suddenly becomes `/user/` and it tries to append that in front of all relative URLs and thus none of them load.

**Solution**

You can either make your links absolute, or change the URI base in the header of your pages (inbetween the `<head> </head>` tags):

```
<base href="/">
```